# Getting appropriate path .exe using pre build environment

Tags: prebuild

I have this solution located in :

```
d:\sandboxes\ndesjardins\source\genius4502\systemsoftware\projectsolution.sln
```

I want to retrieve :

```
d:\sandboxes\ndesjardins\source\genius4502
```

but $SolutionDir only returns

```
d:\sandboxes\ndesjardins\source\genius4502\systemsoftware
```

which I don't want. Is there any way I can retrieve

```
d:\sandboxes\ndesjardins\source\genius4502
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only had to add../ to back from one directory